# jxbrowser howto get response content before redirect

Tags: jxbrowser

I used jxbrowser to tracking data exchange through NetworkDelegate interface, I can get all response data except redirection occurs.

if redirection occurs, the onDataReceived event for original URL will not be happened, so the question is, how can I get response content when redirection occurs, or how to disable automatic redirection.

thanks for any help!

Answer (score 0):

There is no data for the original URL. The response in this case usually contains the status line and Location header. For example:

```
HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently
Location: http://www.example.org/index.asp
```

You can obtain this information in JxBrowser using the following approach:

```
Browser browser = new Browser();
browser.getContext().getNetworkService().setNetworkDelegate(new DefaultNetworkDelegate() {
    @Override
    public void onBeforeRedirect(BeforeRedirectParams params) {
        System.out.println("URL: " + params.getURL());
        System.out.println("New URL: " + params.getNewURL());
        System.out.println("Response code: " + params.getResponseCode());
    }
});
```

Comment: Is there a way how to stop that redirect (in my case I have own authentication mechanism and I want to detect when page is redirecting to login page) so i want to stop redirect, let user authenticate and than reopen page with authentication context